Adding Rows in DataGridView on form without writing the syntax DataGridView1.Rows.Add(3)
The thread question is clear and specific ie. to add rows in DGV1 on Form without writing its syntax (programmatically
The reason i want is to work around with cells in DGV1 is for Numbering cells its Location and size
Also the Cells in DGV1 are square as per below code
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(3)
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Height = 76
        Next i
  For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Columns(i).Width = 76
        Next i

so when i add 3 rows as per above i get Row 1 on Top with values
Row 2 in Middle with values and
Row 3 in Bottom
with following syntaxes
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value ="1"
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value ="2"
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value ="3"

DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value ="4"
DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value ="5"
DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(3).Value ="6"

DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value ="7"
DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(2).Value ="8"
DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(3).Value ="9"

and by default the columns are three without adding and removing on the DGV1 property.
Ultimately it looks like below
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Basically wanted to re-shuffle the above cells on the Form with above respective values placed differently with further coding i can get its values respectfully. So i thought of placing the cells manually to get the respective values in each cell numbered correctly
4 9 2
8 5 7
3 1 6

Thanks
SsD
Explored on the DGV1 property box if possible to get Cell of DGV1 manually on the form.
I could not find the same to implement it

Why would you need to move cells around? Just change the values. You could create a list of three items with three properties each and bind it to the grid, then manipulate the data in that list and see those changes reflected in the grid.

You could create a list of three items with three properties each and bind it to the grid    Any idea How could I begin with creating the List of 3 items 3 properties etc. As this is  my first time for such a case to work with DGV

It is hard to understand your question. Are you wanting to edit the cells manually at run time?

It is hard to understand your question. Are you wanting to edit the cells manually at run time?    If I get some idea of the different possibilities then I can begin somewhere. Only thing I could begin with DGV was a Square Grid with 9 cells thereafter jmchilnney's  suggestion I am stuck with creating 3 items 3 properties. Any reference one could provide will be of help

Is It in following manner I begin Dim Rows As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

Any reference/URL you can share and I go through it for me to begin.

I would like to edit cells programmatically

jmcilhinney Is this what you meant                                                                            Dim dgv4Row0 As String() = {"4", "9", "2"}  Dim dgv4Row1 As String() = {"8", "5", "7"}  Dim dgv4Row2 As String() = {"3", "1", "6"}    DataGridView4.Rows.Add(dgv4Row0)  DataGridView4.Rows.Add(dgv4Row1)  DataGridView4.Rows.Add(dgv4Row2)
